# Partitions now appearing in /mnt, not /media/$USER

Tags: mount, partition, disk, media

Until I forced a restart on my laptop this morning, I had a partition to my boot drive on which I had previously installed Linux Mint 18 (sensibly labelled "linuxmint") Now I can access the same partition, but it appears in `/mnt` where before it had been in `/media/myname`.

How do I change this back?

Answer (score 0):

Edit appropriate line under /etc/fstab. This will be a second column which is responsible for 'mount target'. Take quick look into man fstab for details. It's easy.